# Copy the value of a specific row and paste it into multiple rows that have the same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that has four columns: ID, Step, col1 and col2.
The step columns have a row that has a NaN value, this is where the data for col1 and col2 are.

I want to fill the missing data of col1 and col2 for each unique ID.

the original data frame looks like:

```
ID        Step   col1       col2      
7001      Nan    1.0        6.0
7001      0      Nan        Nan
7001      1      Nan        Nan
6500      Nan    12.0       3.0
6500      0      Nan        Nan
6500      1      Nan        Nan
```

I want this result:

```
ID        Step   col1      col2
7001      Nan    1.0        6.0
7001      0      1.0        6.0
7001      1      1.0        6.0
6500      Nan    12.0       3.0
6500      0      12.0       3.0
6500      1      12.0       3.0
```

I can't seem to find a good way to do this that is not too long as I have a lot of data to process (10 GB)

Comment: Are the IDs always in order and do you always want to replace the second a following col1 and and col2 with the first? This may be a good use of groupby.

Comment: Is that 10GB in memory, or is the original file that large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is sorted, you can do a `fillna` with `mode="ffill"`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Note that you will have to apply per column, as otherwise the step would be (wrongly) propagated

```
y=pd.read_csv(StringIO(x),sep='\s+',na_values='Nan')
y['col1']=y['col1'].fillna(method='ffill')
y['col2']=y['col2'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

gives:

```
     ID  Step  col1  col2
0  7001   NaN   1.0   6.0
1  7001   0.0   1.0   6.0
2  7001   1.0   1.0   6.0
3  6500   NaN  12.0   3.0
4  6500   0.0  12.0   3.0
5  6500   1.0  12.0   3.0
```

If your data is not ID sorted, you can always sort it first:
`y_sorted= y.sort_values(["ID"])`

Comment: You can just use `.ffill()` instead of `.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: True, `.ffill()` is is a wrapper for exactly the same function. I find the more verbose one a bit more descriptive that I am filling the NaNs

Answer (score 0):

First, It doesn't look like those are proper `NaN` values, let's make them so:

```
df.replace('Nan', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Then we can `ffill()` the desired columns:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].ffill()
```

Ouput:

```
     ID Step  col1 col2
0  7001  NaN   1.0  6.0
1  7001    0   1.0  6.0
2  7001    1   1.0  6.0
3  6500  NaN  12.0  3.0
4  6500    0  12.0  3.0
5  6500    1  12.0  3.0
```